# How do i handle errors in Dio package

Tags: flutter, dart

okay so im using dio package to authenticate users in my app. it works fine but i want to be able to show the error message in a toast message for the user and i have absolutely no idea how to do that. i tried printing the error but i get no response, please help me out im new to dio.

This is my code

```
 class Loginservice extends ILogin {
  @override
  Future<UserModel?> login(
      String username, String password, BuildContext context) async {
    @override
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String api = '$baseUrl/login';

    final data = {"username": username, "pwd": password};
    final dio = Dio();
    Response response;
    response = await dio.post(api, data: data);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final body = response.data;
      var username = body['username'];
      var myToken = body['token'];
      preferences.setString('username', username);
      preferences.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);

          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()));
    
          return UserModel(
            username: username,
            token: body['token'],
          );
        } else {
          print('error');
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in their [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#handling-errors),

> When an error occurs, Dio will wrap the Error/Exception to a
> DioException:

You can wrap the call with a try/ catch to catch them.

```
try {
  // 404
  await dio.get('https://api.pub.dev/not-exist');
} on DioException catch (e) {
  // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
  // that falls out of the range of 2xx and is also not 304.
  if (e.response != null) {
    print(e.response.data)
    print(e.response.headers)
    print(e.response.requestOptions)
  } else {
    // Something happened in setting up or sending the request that triggered an Error
    print(e.requestOptions)
    print(e.message)
  }
}
```

and **DioException** contain these fields,

```
/// The request info for the request that throws exception.
RequestOptions requestOptions;

/// Response info, it may be `null` if the request can't reach to the
/// HTTP server, for example, occurring a DNS error, network is not available.
Response? response;

/// The type of the current [DioException].
DioExceptionType type;

/// The original error/exception object;
/// It's usually not null when `type` is [DioExceptionType.unknown].
Object? error;

/// The stacktrace of the original error/exception object;
/// It's usually not null when `type` is [DioExceptionType.unknown].
StackTrace? stackTrace;

/// The error message that throws a [DioException].
String? message;
```

Personally, I would use a switch statement to catch all the **DioExceptionType** s and handle/ return error messages accordingly.

```
if (error is DioException) {
      switch (error.type) {
        case DioExceptionType.connectionTimeout:
        case DioExceptionType.receiveTimeout:
        case DioExceptionType.sendTimeout:
          networkFailure = const NetworkFailure.requestTimeout();
          break;
        case DioExceptionType.badCertificate:
          networkFailure = const NetworkFailure.badCertificate();
    ...
```

you can find all the exception types [here](https://github.com/cfug/dio/blob/main/dio/lib/src/dio_exception.dart) or you can simply go to the plugin source in your flutter app.

Answer (score 1):

### Handling Errors in Dio Package: Best Practices and Strategies

.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:beech_app/shared/network/internet_connection.dart';
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import 'package:beech_app/shared/model/error_model.dart';
import 'package:beech_app/shared/network/status_code.dart';

final dioConsumerProvider = Provider((ref) {
  final dio = Dio();
  return NetworkService(
    dio,
    ref.watch(internetConnectionProvider),
  );
});

class NetworkService {
  final Dio _client;
  final InternetConnection _internetConnection;

  // Constructor
  NetworkService(this._client, this._internetConnection) {
    _client.options = clientOptions;

    if (kDebugMode) {
      _client.interceptors.add(LogInterceptor(requestBody: true, responseBody: true));
    }
  }

  final Map<String, Object> headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
  };
  late var clientOptions = BaseOptions(
    baseUrl: 'http://192.168.1.2:3000/api/v1',
    headers: headers,
    responseType: ResponseType.plain,
    followRedirects: false,
    validateStatus: (status) {
      return status! < StatusCode.internalServerError;
    },
  );

  // Method to make network requests
  Future<Either<FailureModel, T?>> makeRequest<T>(
    String path, {
    String method = 'GET',
    bool formDataIsEnabled = false,
    dynamic data,
    required T Function(dynamic json) fromJson,
    Map<String, dynamic>? queryParams,
  }) async {
    // Check for internet connection
    if (await _internetConnection.isConnected == false) {
      final errorModel = FailureModel(message: 'Please connect to the Internet');
      return Left(errorModel);
    }

    try {
      // Make the request
      final response = await _client.request(
        path,
        queryParameters: queryParams,
        options: Options(method: method),
        data: formDataIsEnabled ? FormData.fromMap(data!) : data,
      );

      // Handle successful response
      if (response.statusCode! >= 200 && response.statusCode! < 300) {
        final dataJson = _handleResponseAsJson(response);
        final data = fromJson(dataJson);
        return Right(data);
      } else {
        // Handle error response
        final errorModel = FailureModel(
          statusCode: response.statusCode,
          message: response.statusMessage ?? "Something went wrong",
        );
        return Left(errorModel);
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      // Handle DioException
      final errorMsg = _handleDioError(e);
      final errorModel = FailureModel(
        statusCode: e.response?.statusCode,
        message: errorMsg,
      );
      return Left(errorModel);
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle other exceptions
      final errorModel = FailureModel(message: e.toString());
      return Left(errorModel);
    }
  }

  // Helper method to decode response body as JSON
  dynamic _handleResponseAsJson(Response<dynamic> response) {
    final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.data);
    return responseJson;
  }

  // Method to update headers
  Map<String, dynamic>? updateHeader(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final header = {...data, ...headers};
    _client.options.headers = header;

    return header;
  }

  // Helper method to handle different types of Dio exceptions
  String _handleDioError(DioException error) {
    switch (error.type) {
      case DioExceptionType.connectionTimeout:
      case DioExceptionType.sendTimeout:
      case DioExceptionType.receiveTimeout:
        return "Timeout occurred while sending or receiving";
      case DioExceptionType.badResponse:
        final statusCode = error.response?.statusCode;
        if (statusCode != null) {
          switch (statusCode) {
            case StatusCode.badRequest:
              return "Bad Request";
            case StatusCode.unauthorized:
            case StatusCode.forbidden:
              return "Unauthorized";
            case StatusCode.notFound:
              return "Not Found";
            case StatusCode.conflict:
              return 'Conflict';

            case StatusCode.internalServerError:
              return "Internal Server Error";
          }
        }
        break;
      case DioExceptionType.cancel:
        break;
      case DioExceptionType.unknown:
        return "No Internet Connection";
      case DioExceptionType.badCertificate:
        return "Internal Server Error";
      case DioExceptionType.connectionError:
        return "Connection Error";
      default:
        return "Unknown Error";
    }
    return "Unknown Error";
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

response has two factors: statusMessage and statusCode.

Why don't you try this.

change A to B

A

```
} else {
      print('error');
    }
```

B

```
} else {
      print('${response.statusMessage}');
      print('${response.statusCode}');
    }
```

or

```
import 'dart:developer';
...
} else {
      log(response);
      log('${response.statusMessage}');
      log('${response.statusCode}');
    }
```